# MahApps.Metro NumericUpDown events workaround

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mahapps.metro

I am experiencing an odd issue, and have not found anyone else experiencing similar from my searches.
What I have is a NumericUpDown and I simply want to call a method when either the + or - buttons are pressed.
So i could see 2 options :
ValueDecremented & ValueIncremented events
or, better yet
ValueChanged event.
But it's not behaving as expected,on either option.
I have stripped it right down to just display a messagebox with the value as follows :

```
private void num_ZoneDistance_ValueIncremented(object sender, MahApps.Metro.Controls.NumericUpDownChangedRoutedEventArgs args)
{
        MessageBox.Show(num_ZoneDistance.Value.ToString());
}
private void num_ZoneDistance_ValueDecremented(object sender, MahApps.Metro.Controls.NumericUpDownChangedRoutedEventArgs args)
{
        MessageBox.Show(num_ZoneDistance.Value.ToString());
}
```

And alternatively :

```
private void num_ZoneDistance_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double?> e)
{
        MessageBox.Show(num_ZoneDistance.Value.ToString());
}
```

But with the first set, it's 1 out. ie. If it's on 4 and I press +, it reports 4 THEN updates to 5, which is not what I'd expect, if it only updates after the associated event, what's the point?

With the second option, ValueChanged, it reports the correct - updated - value, however the event fires when the window loads( as well as at correct time), during component initialization - and that causes crashes because dependent objects are created yet - and i have no idea why the event would trigger onload.

The only workaround I have found is to user the first option, and manual add/substract 1 from the value, but does anyone have a better suggestion? because surely both options should just work anyway, as I understand them.

Thanks

**EDIT :**
Going with num_ZoneDistance_ValueChanged event
And then placed inside it a check on num_ZoneDistance.Value!=null
Avoids the crash on loading up, doesn't explain why the event is triggered at that point, but maybe it's me misinterpreting expected behavior, either way checking it isn't null circumvents the issue, and ValueChanged reports correct values unlike ValueIncremented & ValueDecremented, that both report the previous value, and it reduces it to 1 method instead of 2.

Comment: I am the developer of this control. I will look into that issue in the next few days. Do you have a sample project where I can see the strange behavior immediately?

Comment: i had a lot of surrounding stuff, but i have made a new, clean project with the only a numericupdown, and behaviour is repeated, gladly provide that if i have any means to get it to you, but it really just is mahapps.metro NumericUpDown on empty window with the above code.

Comment: @LouisM. you really should use the NumericUpDownChangedRoutedEventArgs in your events!!! that's recommended.

Comment: @punker76 as pointed out on your post below, that removes the hardcoded +-1 values, to always reflect the specified interval, which is great, but doesn't fix the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Interval` property of the `NumericUpDownChangedRoutedEventArgs` to show or work with it.

```
private void num_ZoneDistance_ValueIncremented(object sender, MahApps.Metro.Controls.NumericUpDownChangedRoutedEventArgs args)
{
    MessageBox.Show(args.Interval.ToString());
}

private void num_ZoneDistance_ValueDecremented(object sender, MahApps.Metro.Controls.NumericUpDownChangedRoutedEventArgs args)
{
    MessageBox.Show(args.Interval.ToString());
}
```

If you need it, you can change the `Interval` property at the events.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well it's better than hard coding +-1 ,  using +- interval instead, doesn't fix the poor control behavior as such, but anything that reduces hard coding values is good